# excel - index match multiple criteria & MIN function

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am having some issues with the following task. 
I am trying to get the unique ID of a product corresponding to the following criteria:

For each day (first column), each Issuer (say, issuer 1) and Type of product(say, B) I want the ID corresponding to the smallest % for that day, that issuer and that product type.

thank you very much.

[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you looked into `MINIFS`?

Comment: Have you managed to come up with a MINIFS for the percent?

Answer (score 0):

According to the following image, put this in J2 and drag it down.

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$99)/((B$2:B$99=G2)*(C$2:C$99=H2)*(D$2:D$99=I2)*(E$2:E$99=AGGREGATE(15, 7, (E$2:E$99)/((B$2:B$99=G2)*(C$2:C$99=H2)*(D$2:D$99=I2)), 1))), 1))
```

[image]